# Cygwin: ssh and ssh-keygen do not react at all

Tags: ssh, cygwin, ssh-keygen

I've got a strange behaviour of ssh and ssh-keygen: they do not react at all. Cygwin is started with admin rights and works normally. The host 192.168.1.1 is up and I can remote desktop to it:

When I try:

```
$ ssh -vvv pi@192.168.1.1
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

I get only one line but nothing else, even if I wait hours. I reinstalled cygwin, openssh, I deleted the .ssh folders, no success.

When I enter

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

nothing happens at all. For me it seems that the user interaction does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Update: I tried:

1. reinstalling cygin for all users, one user, running the installation with admin rights, without. No success.
2. Started ssh and ssh-keygen with an absolute path to make sure that the windows openssh is not used
3. Checked the folder permissions on .ssh

Here is my strace:   [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FJfUj3C1)

Update 2: I found the following: if I run ssh-keygen or ssh often enough (!) it will sometimes work! Now that's weird.

Comment: They may have problems reading ssh config files. What you get if you do `ls -l $HOME/.ssh` ?

Comment: Hi Philippe,   thanks. I get `$ ls -l $HOME/.ssh
total 6
-rw------- 1 Marc None 2610 Dec 31 09:21 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 Marc None  574 Dec 31 09:21 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 Marc None  173 Dec 31 09:24 known_hosts`

Comment: Can you run `strace ssh -vvv pi@192.168.1.1` ? to see in which system call it was stuck.

Comment: Thanks, that creates quite some output  [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FJfUj3C1)

Comment: How did you install cygwin ? Did you follow the procedure in https://www.cygwin.com/ ?

Comment: Hi Philippe, yes. I reinstalled it three times. Just download and running setup as admin. During the installation I installed bash and openssh. So strange. I'm using cygin since about 10 years.

Comment: I don't any mention of `admin` in installation procedure. Can you install just using normal user ?

Comment: Hi Philipp, I installed it as user, as admin, running cygwin with admin rights, as user. It doesn't make a change.

Comment: Aditionally, I found the following: if I run ssh-keygen or ssh often enough (!) it will sometimes work!

Comment: In strace result, I see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\epclient64.dll`. What Citrix has to do with ssh  ?

Comment: Indeed, I went after that topic for an hour, googling the dll, disabling citrix at startup. I also think that citrix should not listen to any outgoing (!) ssh connections.

Comment: Ok Philippe, that was the right hint! I uninstalled citrix and it works. If citrix is installed it would work only 1 out of 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is down to a bug in epclient64.dll of citrix: it crashes my ssh in my internal network. After uninstallation of citrix it would work normally. Here is the log

```
Pastebin log of strace
https://pastebin.com/FJfUj3C1[Pastebin][1]
```

Without the app protection it works fine. So to sum up:

- with app protection ssh crashes again and again, it does not even start properly
- without citrix ssh works fine
- citrix without app protection ssh works fine

--> epclient64.dll does not work with ssh

And we are talking about the most recent versions of ssh & citrix as of Jan 2021.

Answer (score 2):

[Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125671/philippe) had the right idea. Basically the citrix workspace app is crashing ssh cygwin. When I uninstalled citrix everything worked fine!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I even observed differences between an existing and a fresh cygwin installation where the former wouldn't react at all but with the latter ssh-* commands would work once after startup, but only once. How odd :/

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I uninstalled citrix, it had no effect.

I opened up the folder in Windows Explorer where the `ssh.exe` resides.  I right clicked on this executable, navigated to Compatibility tab, selected Run this program in compatibility mode for "Windows 8".  Then I at least got a response from the command line, but it would never connect to the host I entered.  It would get stuck and I would have to kill it from taskmgr.

When I ran `whereis ssh`, I had 2 versions in Cygwin, one in `/usr/bin` and one in `/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH`.  So what I did was to move the `/usr/bin` version to a backup file and create a link in a cygwin shell to `/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`.  Now it works like it used to.

By the way my OpenSSH version is "OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5" running on Windows 10.